# How to configure SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN for local builds in Expo EAS without exposing in eas.json?

Tags: expo, sentry, eas

I'm working on an Expo project and have successfully integrated Sentry [following the instructions](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/). For cloud builds using EAS Cloud, I've set the SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN in the EAS Secret, and everything works seamlessly.

However, I'm facing a challenge for local builds. According to the [updated documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/#add-the-config-plugin:%7E:text=SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,EAS%20Build.), it suggests placing the SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN inside the eas.json file. But, eas.json should not be part of the .gitignore, so following this approach, my token will be exposed.

What's the best way to configure Sentry for local EAS builds without exposing the token? Has anyone else faced this challenge, and is there a recommended solution or best practice?

I have tried to add it to the .env but with no success.

Answer (score -1):

To configure Sentry for local EAS (Expo Application Services) builds without exposing your token, you can use environment variables in a safe way. The .env file is a good approach, but you need to ensure that it's kept out of version control for security reasons.

Here's how you can do it:

Create a .env file: If you haven't already, create a .env file in the root directory of your project.

Add your environment variable: Inside the .env file, add your Sentry authentication token as an environment variable like this:-

SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN=your_auth_token_here

Use a package to load environment variables: To safely load environment variables from your .env file during local development, you can use a package like dotenv. Install it using npm or yarn

```
npm install dotenv
```

Load environment variables in your project: In your project's entry file (e.g., index.js or the main script), add the following code to load the environment variables from the .env file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Access the environment variable: You can now access the SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN environment variable in your code like this:

```
const sentryAuthToken = process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN;
```

And,start.

Comment: Thank you! The last sentence of my post states that i have already tried that, but it doesn't seems to be reading the value from it